# A student walks in to class to discover the had forgotten to study for a quiz. The quiz has 10 True-False questions

Tags: probability

I understand how to find the probability of the student passing the quiz where passing is 60% by figuring out the chance of 6, 7, 8, 9, or 10 correct and adding them up.  [(.5)^10]*[10!/(4!)(6!)] + (7correct) + (8 correct) + (9 correct) + (10 correct) = 0.376953125 ~ 38%

However, there is a part B to this question
"Instead, if the student has been paying attention in class and is confident of three of the answers selected, what is the probability of the student getting a 70% on the quiz, assuming the student's confidence is justified?

I'm really horrible with this discrete stuff.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes your answer to part (a) is correct.  For part (b) just pretend it is a very similar question to (a) except it is only a seven-question quiz that the student will guess on instead of a ten-question quiz and the student needs four (*or more if we are talking about getting at least the desired score rather than exactly the desired score*) questions to be guessed correct in order to receive the desired score.

Comment: So do I figure out the the chance of 4, 5, 6, 7 correct and add them up? [(.5)^7]*[7!/(3!)(4!)] +  [(.5)^7]*[7!/(2!)(5!)] + (6 correct) + (7 correct) = prob

Comment: How off am I on that?  I'm still a little confused

Comment: That would have been correct had we been asking the question of "*...what is the probability of the student getting* **at least** *a 70% on the quiz*" rather than the question of "*...what is the probability of the student getting* **exactly** *a 70% on the quiz.*"  Unfortunately, the question did not include either of the phrases "at least" or "exactly" so we need to make an assumption as to which is intended.  I would lean towards assuming we were looking for exactly a 70%.

Comment: Yes thank you I understand.  I wasn't realizing that at first.  So I just need to figure out getting 4 correct.  7!/(4!*3!)*1/2^7=0.2734...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for probablity of a student getting exactly 7 questions correct we start by getting 3 questions out,since they will be correct. That leaves us with 7 questions and we need 4 correct answers. It should look like 7!/(4!*3!)*1/2^7=0.2734...

Comment: Oh so it's not about passing, since this question states exactly a 70% we only need to figure out 4 correct answers (since we are given 3) and then we are done?  7!/(4!*3!)*1/2^7=0.2734 so... 27% chance to get a 70%?

Answer (score 3):

For part B, assuming he is confident and his confidence is justified in order to get 70% he must get 4 correct out of remaining 7 questions, So just find P(X=4) taking n=7